# WooCommerce / WordPress / Image = How to link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a piece of code that looks like the below, and what it does is display the Featured Image of a WooCommerce product, as well as the title of that Product. If somebody clicks on the thumbnail or title, they are directed back to the Individual Product page.

BUT: What if I want to click (left-click mind you) on the thumbnail and have the original sized image to display?
Is it as simple as using the **the_post_thumbnail_url** tag? It doesn't seem to work that easily, I'm guessing because it is a WooCommerce image and the prod_id and filters are likely needed.

```
                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>">
                            <?php echo $product->get_image() ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product', $item['prod_id'] ) ) ) ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_in_cartproduct_obj_title', $product->get_title(), $product ) ?></a>
                        <?php do_action( 'yith_wcwl_table_after_product_name', $item ); ?>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I've come up with, and it works.

```
                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product->get_id(), 'full' ) ) ?>">
                            <?php echo $product->get_image() ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
```